# Spring Security with Spring Session: how to forbid updating of session last access time for particular requests

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-session

The thing I want to do is to exclude requests on `/my-path` from any checks by Spring Security. The problem is that I have a path `/my-path`. And requests for this path should not update the last access time in Spring Session. 
The way the request passes is through `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`, where the filter loads the context via `SecurityContextRepository`. And the `SecurityContextRepository` gets the session, which updates last accessed time.
So the question is: Is it possible to exclude requests on `/my-path` from any sessions checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<http pattern="/my-path" security="none"/>
```

or Java config

```
web.ignoring().antMatchers("/my-path");
```